# How to properly call the callback in setState(updater[, callback])?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, setstate

So I have been struggling to pass a callback to `this.setState()`, because I was doing this way :

`this.setState({ anyState }, this.anyFunction());`
The function was called, but it wasn't called really after the state was updated. In result, as I was also updating the same `anyState` in my `anyFunction`, there was some kind of a conflict between the two state updates, and only the first one was effective.

Then I discovered that I had to do either

`this.setState({ anyState }, () => this.anyFunction());`

either

`this.setState({ anyState }, function() { this.anyFunction() });`

to make things work properly.

Why so ? Why seems my first approach wrong ?

Comment: `this.anyFunction()` *executes* the function. `() => this.anyFunction()` *delays* the function execution. Since `setState` expects a callback, then you should be giving it a function reference, not executing the function immideately via `this.anyFunction()` which will pass in whatever the return value of `this.anyFunction` is, or `undefined` if there is no explicit `return` statement.

Comment: As a guess I would say that you have been calling function, not passing reference to it in `this.setState({ anyState }, this.anyFunction());`

Comment: "*How to properly call the callback*" - that's precisely the problem. You are supposed to *pass* a callback *function*, you should *not call* it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @vlaz, clear as water. Put it as the answer if you can, then I can validate it. Far more clear now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you are using the result of the function as a second argument.

Say `this.anyFunction` returns a constant `"some_text"`, using

```
this.setState({ anyState }, this.anyFunction());
```

is the same as using

```
this.setState({ anyState }, "some_text");
```

In the second example, you are actually passing a callback.  Or a function as an argument.  That function is not executed yet, it will be executed at the end of setState().

For more information about asynchronous programming and callbacks, you can watch this talk: https://javascript-conference.com/javascriptecmascript/asynchronicity-concurrency/

Answer (score 3):

The first approach passes the result of the call to `this.anyFunction` as the callback. Most likely, this is not what you want.

To fix this, you need to remove the parenthesis, i.e. change the code to this:

```
this.setState({ anyState }, this.anyFunction);
```

However, this has the problem, that the `this` binding inside `anyFunction` will no longer point to the class instance. To fix this, you would either need to declare `anyFunction` as an arrow function or explicitly bind `this`.

Comment: I think binding necessity depends on the circumstances. For example, if `setState` occurs in `componentDidmount` or any other bond method it is not necessary to bind `anyFunction` here.